# Rails ERB: when to use :locals=> {:foo => @bar} vs just foo: @bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails ERB, what's the difference?

```
<%= render partial: 'whatever', :locals=> {:foo=> @bar} %>  

 <%= render partial: 'whatever', :foo=> @bar %>
```

Answer (score 2):

> [If you're not going](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html) to be using any of the options like `collections` or `layouts`, you can also use the short-hand defaults of render to render partials.

```
# Instead of <%= render partial: "account", locals: { account: @buyer } %>
<%= render "account", account: @buyer %>
```

Comment: `<%= render "account", account: @buyer %>` raises error `undefined local variable or method account` instead need to use `<%= render "account", object: @buyer %>` @Arup

Comment: According to the document we need to use `<%= render "account", object: @buyer %>`, otherwise it through error for me @Arup

Comment: I don't know where are you seeing this.. Read [The :as and :object options](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html) section.. and also read *Rendering the default case* section in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use

```
<%= render partial: 'whatever', :locals=> {:whatever => @bar} %>
```

same as

```
<%= render partial: 'whatever', :object => @bar %>
```

_whatever.html.erb

```
<%= whatever %>
```

Here the [Reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html#class-ActionView::PartialRenderer-label-The+-3Aas+and+-3Aobject+options)